# Having issue with copy string values im between arrays

Tags: c, arrays

I have been working on some code that tokenizes a string from a line and then creates a temp array to copy the string into it (called copy[]) and it is filled with 0's initially (The end game is to split this copy array into temp arrays of length 4 and store them in a struct with a field char* Value). For some reason my temp arrays of size 4 end up having a size of 6.

```
char* string = strtok(NULL, "\"");
printf("%s", string);                         
int len = (int)strlen(string);

while(len%4 != 0) {
   len++;
}
char copy[len];
for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
   copy[i] = '0';
}
printf("%s\n", copy);

int copyCount = 0;
int tmpCount = 0;
char temp[4];
while (copyCount < len) {
   if(tmpCount == 4) {
       tmpCount = 0;
   }
   while(tmpCount < 4) {
       temp[tmpCount] = copy[copyCount];
       tmpCount++;
       copyCount++;
   }
   printf("%s %d\n", temp, (int)strlen(temp));  
}
```

This yields:

```
This is the end
0000000000000000
This is the end0
This� 6
 is � 6
the � 6
end0� 6
```

And should yield:

```
This is the end
0000000000000000
This is the end0
This 4
 is  4
the  4
end0 4
```

I've been messing around with this for awhile and can't seem to figure out why its making temp have a length of 6 when I set it to 4. Also I'm not sure where the random values are coming from. Thanks!

Comment: Your snippet of code shows the first call to strtok as char* string = strtok(NULL, "\""); Have you called it once with the string to tokenize passed as the first argument?

Comment: Shouldn't you allocate "copy" array?

Comment: @AdrianKrupa I thought so too, but after looking around on SO for a minute it looks like `char copy[len];` is valid C code nowadays, even in the middle of a function like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that your string `temp` is not null-terminated.  C-style strings should be terminated with a `\0` character.  For some (lucky) reason there is a `\0` three bytes in memory after wherever the end of `temp` lives, so when `strlen` tries to compute its length, it gets 6.  This is also why `printf` is printing garbage: it will print `temp` until it finds the null terminator, and there are garbage characters in memory before `printf` reaches the null terminator.

Comment: So would making temp size 5 and adding a \0 after copying the 4 chars work?

Comment: Yes, it should.  You don't need to add the `\0` repeatedly.  For example: `char temp[5] = "xxxx";` will add the `\0` for you automatically.  You could do this explicitly with `char temp[5]; temp[4] = '\0';`.